# equivalent expressions memset and array

Tags: c

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){

    struct name{

         char array[8];

    };

    struct name na;
    memset(&na.array,0,8); 


 }
```

It is the same **memset(&na.array,0,8);**   that **memset(na.array,0,8)**; ?

and it is the same **na.array** that **&na.array[0]** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is the same memset(&na.array,0,8); that memset(na.array,0,8); ?

Yes.

However, this only means that both variants behave equivalently. `&na.array` and `na.array` have very different types.

`na.array` is of type `char[8]`, an array of eight `char`s. `&na.array` is of type `char(*)[8]`, a *pointer* to an array of eight `char`s.

> and it is the same na.array that &na.array[0] ?

Strictly speaking, no. `na.array` is actually of type `char[8]` while `&na.array[0]` is of type `char *`. However, there is an implicit conversion rule from `char[8]` to `char *`, which is called *decay*. So, `na.array` can *decay* to a `char *`, which is precisely the type of `&na.array[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

> It is the same memset(&na.array,0,8); that memset(na.array,0,8); ?

Same thing, and you should use `sizeof` instead of hardcode the array size.

`memset(&na.array,0,sizeof(na.array));`

Personally I would prefer using `&` to make the address of the array explicit.

Answer (score 1):

The three expressions that you mention produce identical results when passed as parameters to a function taking `void*`. The reasons why it is so are different:

- `&na.array` is the address of the array. It matches the address of its initial element, but it has a different type. However, you are passing it to a function taking `void*`, so the type does not matter.
- `na.array` is the array itself. It "decays" to a pointer to array's initial element when passed to a `void*` parameter.
- `&na.array[0]` is the address of array's initial element, taken directly. It gets converted to `void*` when you pass it as a parameter to `memset`.